# Phalcon won't update record anyway

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm using Model and PHQL to update a record but mysql wont accept any changes.
`SELECT` and `INSERT` are working properly.

sample update with PHQL:

```
UPDATE \Modules\Shared\Models\Airline SET [name] = 'test' WHERE id = '8'
```

Comment: Is it producing any output/error?

Comment: No. without any errors!

Comment: yes, indeed. could you add the error msg to the OP, please.

Comment: Once your are using Model, why not to use update methods providen by model?

Comment: indeed I using Model. above code is a temp test code.

Answer (score 0):

First please add these three lines in top of your `index.php` for showing errors for you if you have disabled error reporting before :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then i think you must use this PHQL :

```
UPDATE \Modules\Shared\Models\Airline SET [\Modules\Shared\Models\Airline].name = 'test' WHERE [\Modules\Shared\Models\Airline].id = '8'
```

Comment: You probably nailed it, cause i guess that `[name] = "test"` should not work at all according to [manual](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/phql.html). This PHQL can go as little as `UPDATE \Modules\Shared\Models\Airline SET name = 'test'` WHERE id = '8'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check a model for the errors.

```
if (!$model->save()) {
   var_dump($model->getMessages());
}
```

If this did not help, look at the model's metadata.